# Macbook 12" doesn't sleep/wake on close/open

Tags: mac, startup, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

I bought an Macbook 12" 2016 which doesn't want so sleep when I close the lid. Furthermore it also doesn't want so start if I open the lid. I tried resetting the SMC and NCRAM, then I reinstalled MACOS. Nothing helped. I also tried to get it so sleep with magnets, this worked out quiet well, so I don't think that the sensors are broken.

Here is my pmset -g output:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    259200
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 gpuswitch            2
 powernap             0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         2
 sleep                1
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 disksleep            10
```

and my pmset -g assertion output:

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 142(WindowServer): [0x0000001800098047] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100000271 name:AppleHIDKeyboardEve product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 120 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your power management settings are excellent. If you say you've already reset all of the controllers that could be causing this problem, then it really could be a hardware failure.

I just don't quite understand how you notice that the computer is not sleeping? In the settings of pmset no process prevents sleep?

My final advice would be to switch to Hibernatemode 25

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

Comment: I noticed it because I played a YouTube video and closed the lid, and the music goes on.

Comment: Setting hidernatemode to 25 doesn't helped either, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Are you charging it?

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are running macOS Ventura

Go to *System Settings > Lock Screen*. Then choose an option for "*Start Screen Saver when inactive*". This will basically have your Mac have Screen Saver activate after a set amount of time.

Next step : still in *System Settings > Lock Screen*, choose an option for "*Turn display off when inactive*". This will just turn off the display after a defined amount of time.

As a matter of safety, also consider disabling "*Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off*". This can be found in *System Settings > Displays > Advanced*.

#### For macOS Monterey and earlier

Go to *System Preferences > Energy Saver*. From here, drag the slider to the wanted inactivity time for display to turn off and disable "*Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off*".